# Accessing my python graphql application deployed in an istio enabled cluster from my front end React app

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, istio, kubernetes-pod

I have a sample react application that queries a Graphql Python application to just print a list of hardcoded employee names on the screen.
I have deployed both of these applications on a cluster and an istio-enabled namespace.

Currently, I am accessing the graphql python application through an External Load Balancer from within my React app.
Like this -

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://**<<<External-ELB>>**:5555/graphql"
})

//appolo client setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link

})
class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>

        <div className="main">
          <h1> Employee Data List</h1>
          <Routes />
        </div>

      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried creating a Virtual service for my application and adding the **istio-ingress-gateway** ELB in the place of **External-ELB**, which works fine but I can still access my graphql app through the browser, which I want to avoid.

Is there any way to handle this with Istio envoy proxies?

I only want to expose my front end with Istio-Ingress-ELB and access my back end application without being exposed.
Now, How do I access My python application without exposing it as a Load Balancer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding to it...I have deployed my application in a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: It would be better to add that directly to the question, but yes, it looks like you are using K8s.  Could you please share your Ingress config and services?  It looks like it is merely needed creating a ClusterIP service for graphQL and access it by react app.

Comment: @Nick 
Yes i am using k8s.. And even when I am creating ClusterIP service for my graphql i am not able to access it from the react app. Because the react app is being accessed from an external browser.